# Why doesn't this middleware for preflight request work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I know the post request will launch a preflight request before the actual post request send. So I made a middleware to handle all the preflights in Express like this:

/app.js:

```
const express=require('express');
const preflightRouter=require('./routes/preflight');

const app=express();

app.use(preflightRouter);  // *    preflightRouter is the middleware handling all the preflight requests.
app.post('/post', (req, res)=>{
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.send('Post requests successful.')
})

app.listen(5000, ()=>{
    console.log('server running on port 5000');
})
```

/routes/preflight:

```
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();

router.options('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    console.log('Preflight hit.')
    res.end();
})

module.exports=router;
```

It got CORS error:[image]

However, if change the * line to this, it works:

```
app.use('/post',preflightRouter);
```

I wondering why it has to perfectly match the entire route path? Isn't it "middleware mounted without a path will be executed for every request to the app" as the express tutorial says?

For completeness, here's the code of front web (frontend port 5500, backend port 5000):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id='btn'>POST</button>
        <script>
            btn.onclick=()=>{
                axios.post('http://localhost:5000/post', {name: 'Smith'})
                .then(response=>{
                    console.log(response);
                })
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the battle-tested [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) middleware?

Comment: The reason yours doesn't work is because you've only added the `preflightRouter` on `OPTIONS /` but your request URL is `/post`

Comment: @Phil Let's say a preflight request send to the backend. `app.use(preflightRouter)` should also receive this request and hanlde it using `OPTIONS /`. The preflight request only needs `OPTIONS /`, doesn't it? The `path` parameter of `app.use([path,] callback)` is optional because it defaults to "/". I don't know which part is wrong.

Comment: @Phil Oh I get it. In `preflight.js`, `router.options` should perfectly match the request URL, like this `router.options('/post', callback)`, instead of `router.options('/', callback)`.

Comment: Your real issue is that you've written your `preflightRouter` not as [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) but as a [route handler](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). Seriously, just use the [cors middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) or at the very least, take a good look at its [source code](https://github.com/expressjs/cors/blob/master/lib/index.js)